# How can I create a text file using the Win+R interface?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, there is the interface "Run", and I want to create a file from that interface.

Comment: What do you mean by create a file? Create an empty file? Launch some editor with a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `cmd /c echo "Contents" > C:\path\filename.txt`

Comment: thank you, this is it

Answer (score 0):

All the Run commands can do is run an application. If you wish to create a file (batch file just say) run Notepad.

So press Win + R and type in note and Notepad should show up.

You can run Word this way as well.

There is no regular extension .CMD so you would create a Batch File (.BAT) or Text file (.TXT).  .COM is a program but you generally cannot create a running .COM program from a command line.

So just run an App and create a text file that way

Comment: Win+R `notepad "%userprofile%\desktop\file.txt"`